# Python joining a list by "\"

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Lets say I have a list of elements.

```
l = ["xf3", "x03", "x8c"] etc.
```

Now I would like to join the elements inside my list with a "\". I tried `r"\".join(l)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["xf3", "x03", "x8c"]
'\\'.join(l)
```

The important part is to escape the `'\\'` as inn Python Strings:

> the backslash "\" is a special character, also called the "escape"
>   character. It is used in representing certain whitespace characters:
>   "\t" is a tab, "\n" is a newline, and "\r" is a carriage return. As well "\"
>   can be used to escape itself: "\" is the literal backslash character.

Comment: OP already know about `join`. Their problem was they did not escape \ so that should be the focal point of any relevant answer

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DeepSpace I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used to escape 'special' characters, hence a Python string can not terminate with a single `\` because it escapes the closing quote.

You have to escape it by using a second `\`, ie `'\\'.join(l)`

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming is what you actually want is to create a string containing those escaped characters. The easiest way I can think of is `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("'\\" + "\\".join(l) + "'")
'ó\x03\x8c'
```

This works by first creating a string of those strings joined by backslash characters (`xf3\x03\x8c`), surrounding those by quotes and adding the initial backslash (`'\xf3\x03\x8c'`), and finally, by evaluating it as a literal, to turn it from a length 12 string into a length 3 string.